# React Context is not updating

Tags: reactjs, react-context

I've switched from nesting props to my components into React's Context API. I've created a class to serve me some desired methods:

```
export default class StepDatabase {
  private readonly steps: Steps = steps;
  private currentStep: number = steps[0].step;

  public getStep(): Step {
    return this.steps[this.currentStep];
  }

  public nextStep(): void {
    if (this.currentStep === this.steps.length) return;
    this.currentStep++;
  }
}
```

And then, created a context:

```
const stepsInstance = new StepsDatabase();
export const StepsContext = createContext<StepsDatabase>(stepsInstance);
```

Of course, then provided it:

```
const App = () => (
    <div className={styles.App_container}>
      <main className={styles.App_grid}>
        <StepsContext.Provider value={stepsInstance}>
          <Sidebar />
          <Content />
        </StepsContext.Provider>
      </main>
    </div>
);
```

And tried using it in my `Sidebar` component:

```
const Sidebar = () => {
  const StepContext = React.useContext(StepsContext);
  const currentStep = StepContext.getStep();

  return (
    <section className={`${styles.App_gridItem} ${styles.App_sideItem}`}>
      <SidebarHeading>{currentStep.stepName}</SidebarHeading>
      <SidebarParagraph>{currentStep.stepDescription}</SidebarParagraph>

      <button onClick={() => StepContext.nextStep()}>step</button>
    </section>
  );
};
```

But the `SidebarHeading` and `SidebarParagraph` wasn't updating at all after clicking my button. The first step has worked fine. What's the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing in your code that triggers the context to re-render.  If the context does not re-render, it won't be able to trigger all of the components that consume it.  You need something at a higher level to cause the context to re-render, or you need to pass a function within your context to your consumers that may trigger the re-render.  See the [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#updating-context-from-a-nested-component).

Here is [an example](https://codesandbox.io/s/fervent-dubinsky-wsu99?file=/src/App.js) based upon your code:

```
import React, { createContext, useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

const StepsContext = createContext();

const Sidebar = () => {
  const { step, setNextStep } = React.useContext(StepsContext);

  return (
    <section>
      <div>Heading: {step.stepName}</div>
      <div>Paragraph: {step.stepDescription}</div>

      <button onClick={() => setNextStep()}>step</button>
    </section>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  const [steps, setSteps] = useState([
    { stepName: "Step 1", stepDescription: "My description 1" },
    { stepName: "Step 2", stepDescription: "My description 2" }
  ]);
  const [currentStep, setCurrentStep] = useState(0);

  return (
    <div>
      <main>
        <StepsContext.Provider
          value={{
            step: steps[currentStep],
            setNextStep: function () {
              if (currentStep < steps.length - 1) {
                setCurrentStep(currentStep + 1);
              }
            }
          }}
        >
          <Sidebar />
          <div>Content</div>
        </StepsContext.Provider>
      </main>
    </div>
  );
}
```